# ACF Nested Repeater Fields with a Conditional to select a repeatable sub fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, nested-repeater

I am trying to build a simple page builder and I understand that there are many pre-built solutions out there but I need to make this simple for my client. I created a Repeating field that starts with a dropdown menu to select which type of assets need built. From there I have three unique fields that can appear based on the drop down selection.

1. WYSIWYG
2. Repeater to build buttons

   2.a page_link

   2.b text

3.Repeater to build simple links

```
 3.a relationship
```

I am trying to allow the client to first select which of the three options they would like and then if they need to build something else on the page they can use the initial repeater to allow the user to start all over again.

The issue I am seeing is how to correctly order the output based on the order inwhich the data is being saved. I have done a VAR_DUMP and the data is in the correct order, I am just unsure as to the next steps to correctly extract the data and display it on the page.

I would really like to not have to use a prebuilt page build and instead go with this route if possible.

https://www.diigo.com/item/image/53h17/27bm – screenshot